# How to Programatically Enable "Keep Running After Screen Off" In Android?

Tags: android

I would like my application to always run while the screen is off just like Google Chrome in the following picture:

[image]

I'm not quite sure how I would enable this button in my application. Does this button require an extra permission in the manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a component or a permission that you can use it directly.it will just change a boolean flag to use it in code.If you want your app keep running after screen off you should use android services and sync state when screen become on,because services can keep running in background.

Comment: For clarification, I'm more interested in the "boolean flag" you've just stated. I am using android services right now in my application, and I simply want to enable that boolean flag inside my program.

Comment: I don't knew how it exactly work,but I think it use this flag at the onPause  method,if it was false,then stop related service,and if true,it's continue receive data from that web page.